# Independence results on pure algebra

Tags: gr.group-theory, set-theory, lo.logic, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra

I think that the most celebrated result in this direction is Shelah's famous work on Whitehead's Problem:

*Is every abelian group $A$ such that $Ext^1(A, \mathbb{Z})=0$ free?*

This is known to be indepedent of **ZFC** (cf. Shelah, *Whitehead groups may not be free, even assuming CH I* and *II*), and it seems that there is an interesting connection between certain questions of **ZFC** and abelian group theory (cf. Eklof *The affinity of set theory and abelian group theory*).

Another famous work relating algebra and 'higher' set theory is B. L. Osofsky *Homological dimension and the continuum hypothesis* and subsequent works.

Independence results, Martin's axiom, Continuum Hypothesis and large cardinal axioms have proven to be interesting to 'pratical' questions in many areas of mathematics (point-set topology, functional analysis, order theory, etc).

**Is there** any current research trend in using sistematically Independence results and other aspects of 'higher' set theory to understand problems of algebra, such as in the above mentioned mathematical disciplines?

Comment: The following survey by Scholze talks about cardinals, so potentially it could lead to some independence!! 
https://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/scholze/Condensed.pdf

Comment: The other one which comes to the stage again, is strong homology, for example  you can consult the following paper 
https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.09267
There are also some new papers in this direction, in particular of Jeff himself. This may not be directly related to algebra, but...

Comment: @Rahman.M thank you very much!

Comment: Have you looked at Eklof and Mekler "almost free modules: set theoretic methods"? You might find something interesting in there. A simple example "there is a nonreflexive free abelian group iff there is a measurable cardinal"

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti this example is impressive. I will check it!